# Migrating from Apache Cassandra 2.2 to Oracle Coherence Oracle 12

Tags: oracle, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, oracle-coherence, cassandra-2.1

I am looking for a migration path for a Java-based project which uses Apache Cassandra 2.2 to Oracle Coherence 12 – and Oracle 12 backend.
The existing application uses CQL to interact with a 3 node Cassandra cluster.
Elswhere we specifically do not use any ORM (e.g. Hibernate/JPA) but use JDBC to interact with the database directly.

Yes, Cassandra is free while the Oracle solution is quite expensive but this is outside the scope of this question.

Any technical suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options depending on your use case.

1. If you are using the SQL to interact with Cassandra for standard request/response interactions and need to migrate it to use Oracle DB which would require the least code changes and still use a standard approach would be to use an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) tool like Hibernate/JPA and use [Coherence as the L2 cache](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22621/usehibernateascoh.htm#COHIG378) (personally I like MyBatis since you have complete control over the SQL code. You may be able to use this [Coherence integration with MyBatis](https://github.com/akhil/mybatis-coherence) ).
2. If you have other applications/ops users updating the database directly and need those changes to be available to your application then you will need to implement a [CacheStore](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/configforjpa_n.htm#COHIG362) (use your favorite ORM here if you like) to save updates to the database and use [Oracle Golden Gate Hotcache feature](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/golden_g.htm#COHIG4805) to push updates made to the database outside your application to Coherence. Your application will need to be changed to interact with Coherence directly using either their Map interface or using the Coherence Query Language (CQL) which is "SQL like". This approach will have an additional advantage of being able to support any asynchronous use cases you may have as Coherence API supports listening to cache changes (using MapListeners) similar to Cassandra's executeAsync.

I hope this helps.